# AngularJS loading JSON from URL via REST

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I am still a bit new about **AngularJS** and just came across the topics about `service`, `provider`, and `factory`.

I have still problem(s) on:

- How to load JSON response from server via REST.
- Place the loading code in either `service`, `provider`, `factory` in which suits it best.
- Provide encapsulation feature *(getters/setters)* in which `$scope` could watch the changes if the load was successful or not.

Please comment for clarifications.

Comment: Any attempt so far? Have you read official docs?

Comment: http://youtu.be/i9MHigUZKEM

Comment: I have read the official docs about the 3. Yet, I'm confused which among them should be ideal to use in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RESTful functionality is provided by Angular in the ngResource module.
It's better to use $http service for non restful resources

```
var phonecatServices = angular.module('phonecatServices', ['ngResource']);

phonecatServices.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

> The $resource service makes it easy to create a RESTful client with
>   just a few lines of code. This client can then be used in our
>   application, instead of the lower-level $http service.

Please check this link for additional details

> https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

Comment: This might be a newbie response but would that could work if the response page would be JSON from a REST url *(ex. Root/module/id)*?

Comment: Yes you can.
$resource is designed to work with RESTful-style URLs, it's probably not the best choice for a plain, flat file.

Comment: Would this still be applicable if for example I'm going to load a JSON file from local *(ex: ROOT/data/data.json)*?

Comment: Yes it's applicable. IF it's a plain json response you are intending then $http service will do which stands for AJAX. Where as $resource though it handles Restful services, that means it can also be used to call normal web services.